# Git integration with power bi workspace comfilcs

Tags: git, powerbi, workspace

I have a git repo synchronized with a power bi workspace.
I can not update the report in the workspace.
I have 4 pending updates: 2 with added status and 2 with delete status.
I can not chose the one to keep.
How should I resolve this?

Thanks.

error:
Unable to complete action

We can't complete this action because multiple items have the same name. Change the name or item type and try again.

Time Mon Oct 02 2023 10:29:32 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

I tried the update all button but comes with an error (see above)
I tried to deploy the report from power bi desktop, I have then 2 pending changes that I can not commit. I can just undo. Which I did but comes to the initial point.

How should I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced and resolved this problem by doing the below.

1. Deleted the changed report from my local machine and committed to dev ops and to the workspace. That removed the report from the workspace altogether.
2. Add the report back into the repo on local machine and commit to dev ops/workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Make a new commit to your repository with a renamed copy of your report. Make another commit where you delete the original report and folders (I assume it's a pbip file.) Merge into the branch which is synced to your workspace and update the workspace.
- Disconnect your workspace and manually delete what needs to be removed from the workspace, then reconnect and re-sync from your repository.